# Aligning Python Class & Super-Class

Tags: python, class, derived-class

Consider the following Python code snippet where we define a `Portfolio`, `Company` and `Deposit` class. A `Portfolio` object simply acts as a union of companies & deposits. And we can run metrics on the portfolio like `Profit`. Questions:

1. For every new metric I include in the `Company` or `Deposit` class I need to manually add a corresponding function in the `Portfolio` class; despite the fact that their behaviour is always the same: sum across all investments. Is there a way to improve this logic/construction of classes? *What if we need to add 100 other metrics...*
2. The `Deposit` class only has a `Profit` function, but not `Loss` (interest in a bank account is assumed to be guaranteed). Is there a way to treat "undefined" metrics as always returning 0? Or is there a cleaner/more correct to define these metrics? *What if we need to cover 100 different investment types that may or may not have different metrics...*

---

```
class Company():
    def __init__(self, ItemsSold, ItemPrice, Expenses, Fines):
        self.ItemsSold = ItemsSold
        self.ItemPrice = ItemPrice
        self.Expenses  = Expenses
        self.Fines     = Fines

    def Profit(self):
        return self.ItemsSold * self.ItemPrice

    def Loss(self):
        return self.Expenses + self.Fines

    def ProfitAndLoss(self):
        return self.Profit() - self.Loss()

class Portfolio():
    def __init__(self, Investments):
        self.Investments = Investments

    def Profit(self):
        return sum([inv.Profit() for inv in self.Investments])

    def Loss(self):
        return sum([inv.Loss() for inv in self.Investments])

    def ProfitAndLoss(self):
        return sum([inv.ProfitAndLoss() for inv in self.Investments])

class Deposit():
    def __init__(self, Notional, InterestRate, TimeHorizon):
        self.Notional     = Notional
        self.InterestRate = InterestRate
        self.TimeHorizon  = TimeHorizon

    def Profit(self):
        return self.Notional * self.InterestRate * self.TimeHorizon        

myComp1 = Company(100,2,50,20)
myComp2 = Company(200,2,100,80)
myDepos = Deposit(100,0.02,3)
myPortf = Portfolio([myComp1,myComp2,myDepos])

print(myPortf.Profit())          # Works fine
print(myPortf.ProfitAndLoss())   # Throws an error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second question is easy: all you have to do is to create a `Base` class where each metrics is defined as a method returning 0. Then derive all your `Invest` classes (`Company`, `Deposit`, etc) from the `Base` class, so as all undefined metrics will call the corresponding method in the `Base` class.

The first question is a bit tougher as it requires some meta-programming. Your `Portfolio` class can also be derived from the `Base` class, then it looks in the method dictionary of the `Base` class (`Base.__dict__`) to retrieve all metrics names. Afterwards, for all these metrics, it creates a specific lambda method that calls this metrics for each item in your `Investments` list and sums up the results. Here is a skeleton code for this:

```
class Base(object):
    def f1(self):
        return 0
    def f2(self):
        return 0

class InvestA(Base):
    def f2(self):
        return 2

class InvestB(Base):
    def f1(self):
        return 1

class Portfolio(Base):
    def __init__(self, invest):
        self.invest = invest
        for name in [n for n in Base.__dict__ if n[:2] != '__']:
           self.__dict__[name] = lambda name=name: self.sum(name)
    def sum(self, name):
        return sum([i.__class__.__dict__[name](i) for i in self.invest
                   if name in i.__class__.__dict__])

A = InvestA()
print("A.f1 = %s, A.f2 = %s" % (A.f1(), A.f2()))
B = InvestB()
print("B.f1 = %s, B.f2 = %s" % (B.f1(), B.f2()))
P = Portfolio([A,A,B])
print('P.f1 = A.f1 + A.f1 + B.f1 =', P.f1())
print('P.f2 = A.f2 + A.f2 + B.f2 =', P.f2())
```

which produces the following output:

```
A.f1 = 0, A.f2 = 2
B.f1 = 1, B.f2 = 0
P.f1 = A.f1 + A.f1 + B.f1 = 1
P.f2 = A.f2 + A.f2 + B.f2 = 4
```

As you can see, A.f1, B.f2, P.f1 and P.f2 are not explicitely defined as methods, but they can be called thanks to inheritance and meta-programming